# Is SBT build considered reliable for a regular deployment without clean?

Tags: scala, jenkins, build, sbt, continuous-deployment

When deploying a Scala application, we use SBT on Jenkins. Currently our build action is specified as `clean assembly` (using [Assembly plugin](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) to produce fat JARs). Our build currently takes between 2-3 minutes, which is sensible, but as the project will become larger and deployments for frequent, it might become a bottleneck.

I remember when doing C++ deployment with Visual Studio, clean (Rebuild All) was necessary, otherwise builds were sometimes (say 0.1%) broken (most likely because build missed some changed dependency in headers).

Is this a concern with SBT? Is `clean` considered a necessary practice to get reliable builds?

Comment: Although `clean` is unnecessary most of the time, I *have* had cases where a `clean` is necessary to get a clean build.

Comment: @MarioCamou Your experience sounds very interesting. Could you perhaps write an answer with more details, like what was specific for the cases where `clean` was necessary and what were the problems you have seen without it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My experience is that sometimes SBT gets mixed-up, the most common thing I've seen is that it can't find classes that are part of the project (and not compiled this time around). I haven't had the inclination to really debug it since doing a `clean` fixes it every time, but for a CI server I would go for `clean` every time.